# How to solve an equation with exponential and trignometric terms.

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to estimate the car's motion in a constant velocity scenario with the variable steering angle (i.e, with constant angular velocity). After manipulating the primary equation I got this:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
e^{k \theta b} & = \cos{(a+bt)} \\
\theta &= \frac{1}{kb}\ln({\cos{(a+bt)}})
\end{array}
\right.
$$

'*θ*' is known for a various time instants '*t*', and '*a*','*b*' are the variables which we need to solve.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It would be helpful to see the equations you're working with

Comment: Those equations are equivalent. You can immediately get the second from the first.

Comment: The two equations are essentially the same, so basically you have only one equation, which is
$$
e^{k \theta b} = \cos{(a+bt)}
$$
You would need to plug in at least two different sets of values in order to get a numerical value for $a$ and $b$. If you know $b$, for example, you can calculate $a$ from
$$
a = \cos^{-1}{\left( e^{k \theta b} \right)} - bt
$$
But for $b$, there's no equation like this. I would try numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{k \theta b} = \cos{(a+bt)} $$
No need to write the second equation which is equivalent to the first equation and so gives nothing more.

In your question you said nothing about the parameter $k$. It is known or not ? If it isn't a known constant your problem involves three unknown parameters, not two.

You wrote : '*θ*' is known for a various time instants '*t*'. One can suppose that the number of 'time instants' is more than 2. True ?

Supposing that they are $n$ measurements : 
$$(t_1,\theta_1), (t_2,\theta_2), ..., (t_k,\theta_k), …, (t_n,\theta_n)  $$
the problem is to adjust the parameters $a,b$ (and may be $k$) for the best fit to the experimental points.

If so, the problem is typically a regression problem, more exactly a nonlinear regression problem due to the parameter $b$ appearing in two places in the equation with non-linearity between them and parameter $a$ .

They are a lot of papers dealing with this kind of problem in books and on the web.

Generally solving for approximate of $a$ , $b$ requires iterative method of calculus. For example :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonlinearLeastSquaresFitting.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares

Also specialized softwares exist for nonlinear regression and curve fitting. Since publicity for commercial packages is not welcome here, a search on the web with key words "software for nonlinear regression" will give you several proposals.

Anyways, it should be profitable for you in oder to get more pertinent answers to edit your question with complementary information about the difficulty you are facing. $\mathbf{\text{A numerical example with available data should be useful to clarify the problem concretely}}$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. 
Yes, and Yes, 'k' is constant, and I know  for various time instants (which is for more than 2 instants). I'm aware of some numerical methods to solve the equation, but I'm looking for some analytical solution.

Comment: OK, $k$ is constant but you don't answer to the question if $k$ is known or not. ? If not this a third parameter to determine in order to optimize the solution.

Comment: OK, I well understand that you are looking for some analytical solution. But the solution of what problem ? Presently we even don't known if is a problem of regression or not.

Comment: OK. You don't think that it is useful to have a numerical example to answer to your question. On the contrary I think that a numerical example would help to understand your problem and to answer to the question for an analytical solution. Since we don't agree, there is no interest for me to continue this discussion

Comment: Hello JJacquelin, thanks for the response. In regard to your questions,

1) 'k' is a known constant, only 'a', 'b' are unknowns.
2) I'm aware of a few numerical solutions such as Newton's method, but I'm looking for an analytical solution (if available). If you are aware of any other numerical solutions, I would be glad to know. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Hello  santhosh Kumar, The mathematical theory relevant to this kind of problem is "Non LInear Regression". One can say nothing more than generalities which can be found in many papers for example from the two links given in my answer. If you want more specific advice well adapted to your problem a numerical example is essential.